# Gulp not producing expected app.css result in laravel 5.3 running in homestead

Tags: gulp, laravel-5.3, laravel-elixir

Gulp is appending a leading '/' to the app.css mix.styles items and the output is consequentially 'unsual' , but the app.js mix.scripts output is perfectly fine. 
The question is - **why is this only happening to the mix.styles portion when the gulpfile.js path structure is essentially the same format?**  and where is the reference to fonts.googleapis coming from?

I'm running laravel 5.3 in homestead in windows 10 bootcamp with PhpStorm

gulp output:

[gulp output - note the leading slash in mix.styles '**/resources** . . .' should just be '**resources** . . .' as in mix.scripts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXkXS.png)

gulpfile.js:

```
const elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

require('laravel-elixir-vue-2');

var vendor_path = 'resources/assets/vendor';

var path = {
    'jquery'     : vendor_path + '/jquery',
    'jqwidgets'  : vendor_path + '/jqx/jqwidgets',
    'jqxscripts' : vendor_path + '/jqx/scripts',
    'bootstrap'  : vendor_path + '/bootstrap'
   };

elixir(function(mix){

  /* Mix Styles */

  mix.styles([
      path.jqwidgets + '/styles/jqx.arctic.css',
      path.jqwidgets + '/styles/jqx.bootstrap.css'
  ],
  'public/css/app.css', '/');

/* Mix scripts */

mix.scripts([
     path.jquery     + '/dist/jquery.js',
     path.bootstrap  + '/dist/js/bootstrap.js',
     path.jqxscripts + '/jquery-1.11.1.min.js',
     path.jqwidgets  + '/jqxcore.js',
     path.jqwidgets  + '/jqxdata.js',
     path.jqwidgets  + '/jqxbuttons.js',
     path.jqwidgets  + '/jqxmenu.js',
     path.jqwidgets  + '/jqxcheckbox.js',
     path.jqwidgets  + '/jqxlistbox.js',
     path.jqwidgets  + '/jqxscrollbar.js',
     path.jqwidgets  + '/jqxdropdownlist.js',
     path.jqwidgets  + '/jqxgrid.js',
     path.jqwidgets  + '/jqxgrid.selection.js'
   ],
    'public/js/app.js', './');

    mix.sass('app.scss')
    .webpack('app.js');
});
```

Here is the app.css output:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,600);
 @import url(/resources/assets/vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css);

 /*# sourceMappingURL=app.css.map */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a strange and simple solution - running 'gulp watch' instead of just 'gulp' as I had been doing, produces the expected app.css result.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code removing the third paramater and it works as expected:

```
mix.styles([
  path.jqwidgets + '/styles/jqx.arctic.css',
  path.jqwidgets + '/styles/jqx.bootstrap.css'
],
'public/css/app.css');
```

Same test for sass and less.

Comment: Did you test my code 'as is' and did it produce an app.css file with the same output as me?

Comment: Are you using Laravel 5.3?  I tried your code without the third parameter - still produces the same result in the app.css file, but the gulp output display no longer displays the leading "/"..  I have no idea where the reference to fonts.googleapis.com/css comes from but this whole thing is still a mystery to me

Comment: Found a strange and simple solution -  running 'gulp watch' instead of just 'gulp' as I had been doing, produces the expected app.css result (on my original code with the third parameter).